# Does Ruby already know the Fibonacci Sequence?

Tags: ruby, recursion, fibonacci

The following method is used to find the nth number in the Fibonacci Sequence:

```rb
def fibonacci(number)
  if number < 2
    number
  else
    fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2)
  end
end

puts fibonacci(6)
```

The answer is `8` (the sixth number in the sequence if you start counting from 1 and not 0 (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8...)

The above code simply deals with the *position* of numbers in the sequence, right? So how does Ruby already know what the value of a number is at a given position? In the words, how does Ruby know that `fibonacci(4)` has the value `3` ? Is the Fibonacci sequence already built in to Ruby?

Comment: [Enumerator::produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce) (new in Ruby v2.7) is convenient for creating a Fibonacci sequence: `Enumerator.produce([0, 1]) { |x, y| [y, x + y] }.take(8).map(&:first) #=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I think your answer is wonderful. You should be writing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sequence is not built in.

`fibonacci` is a recursive function. It will be called nine times (!) to compute `fibonacci(4)` to get `3`. (By the way, this is a terrible approach to calculating Fibonacci numbers. 25 calls for `fibonacci(6)`! It should at least memoize previous calculations.)

Comment: It's just a quick example to ask a bigger question.

Comment: Couldn't an implementation that performs tail call optimization transform this into iterative machine code automatically? No need to lose the elegance of recursiveness if the compiler is good enough.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Tail call optimization just gets rid of the calls. That does not solve the fundamental algorithmic issue with this code, which is the large number of times the same Fibonacci number is recalculated. The way to solve that is with memoization, or better a Fibonacci number array that is filled in and grown as needed with each call.

Answer (score 0):

> So how does Ruby already know what the value of a number is at a given position?

It doesn't already know. It finds out, as part of this method. To find out the value at *this* position, it first calculates all the values of all the numbers at all the *previous* positions.

> how does Ruby know that fibonacci(4) has the value 3

Because the first thing it does in order to calculate `fibonacci(4)` is to call `fibonacci(3)`. The algorithm is recursive.

Comment: Now I get it (scroll down just a bit for the tree diagram) https://medium.com/launch-school/recursive-fibonnaci-method-explained-d82215c5498e